# Imaging library that supports 16bit tiffs

Tags: python, image-processing

I had been using using `PIL` but I just found out that it doesn't support `16bit tiffs`.

I need a library that can do:

1)Image conversion -->`16bit tiff to jpeg`

2)Image resize and crop and of `jpegs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) supports 16bit Tiffs, and they have a wrapper for Python called [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/).